# Im using react-native-vlc-media-player package, video is loading but autoplay, repeat props are not working though?

Tags: react-native, package, components, react-props, video-player

This video itself is working fine without any problems, but the repeat, autoplay, controls props are not working when added to the component, any idea how to solve this issue?

```
<VLCPlayer
              style={{
                width: Width,
                height: Ratio(200),
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginHorizontal: 20,
              }}
              source={{
                uri: !this.state.isPortrait
                  ? this.props.navigation.state.params.video
                  : this.state.videoPath,
              }}
              autoplay={true}
              paused={false}
  />
```

[image]